# Getting the background of a button in Android

Tags: java, android, background

I just started learning android and decided that it would be cool to make a Tic Tac Toe game. I gave all of my buttons an "onClick" method and in there I have the following line of code:     view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);

Now the problem is that if the user presses a button that is already filled with an o, it will change anyway. And so I'd like to have a line of code that could to something like "if the background does not match "R.drawable.x" or "R.drawable.o" then change it.

Apart from this problem, if I want to let the AI make a move, I'll have to know the values of the buttons anyhow, any thought on how I can accomplish this?

How do I go about comparing these?
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Could you use a 2d array and store the states of the buttons. That way you will always know if they are x or o. Plus, I believe you should already have a 2d array to track the x and o since you would need to know that to identify a winner.

Comment: post what  have you tried so far ?

Comment: Looking at another StackOverflow post, I tried something like          if (view.getBackground().equals(getDrawable(R.drawable.x))) {
But this doesn't seem to work either, is there no simple method to compare the background?